# How to delete elements of a pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have a pointer `float *p;` And I want to delete one element of its elements or all of its elements .. Is there any operator can do this??

And `delete [] p;` operator will delete only the address of the pointer or the elements too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But `float *p` is one element (a single pointer to a float). Did you mean `float* p[]` - an array of float pointers?

Comment: What does "its elements" refer to?

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

When you allocate memory using:

```
float* p = new float;
```

You need to deallocate that memory by using:

```
delete p;
```

When you allocate memory using:

```
float* p = new float[some_size];
```

You need to deallocate that memory by using:

```
delete [] p;
```

You cannot deallocate part of the memory you allocated. Regardless of which `new`/`delete` method you use, a call to `delete` will deallocate all the memory allocated by the call to the corresponding `new`.